# Jquery cancel hover event while a toggle event is active

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to cancel a hover event when a toggle event is activated, here is the code

```
$("#fade").toggle(function () {
    if (!v.paused) {
        clearInterval(v.interval);
        v.paused = !0
    }
}, function () {
    if (v.paused) {
        v.interval = setInterval(function () {
            O(g.fwd, !1)
        }, r.animspeed);
        v.paused = !1
    }
})

i.hover(function () {
    if (!v.paused) {
        clearInterval(v.interval);
        v.paused = !0
    }
}, function () {
    if (v.paused) {
        v.interval = setInterval(function () {
            O(g.fwd, !1)
        }, r.animspeed);
        v.paused = !1
    }
})
```

The issue i am having is that that toggle pauses the slider, but if i hover onto the slider and of it, it starts to slide again. I know why it does it, i just don't know how to fix it.

Comment: `v`? `i`? `O`? `g`? `r`? `!0`? It would be preferable if you posted your unminified source.

Comment: I don't think it's minified....

Answer (score 0):

You could make a function that checks if v is paused, and if so, doesn't allow it to happen. For example:

```
$("#fade").toggle(function () {
    if (isvPaused==false) {
        clearInterval(v.interval);
        v.paused = !0
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i figured it out

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem i was haveing, just had to name the functions in the hover event and turn them off and on in the toggle event.

```
 $("#stopgo").toggle(function () {
    if (!v.paused) {
        clearInterval(v.interval);
        v.paused = !0
        i.off('hover', stop());
    }
}, function () {
    if (v.paused) {
        v.interval = setInterval(function () {
            O(g.fwd, !1)
        }, r.animspeed);
        v.paused = !1
        i.on('hover', start())

    }
})

i.hover(function stop() {
    if (!v.paused) {
        clearInterval(v.interval);
        v.paused = !0
    }
}, function start() {
    if (v.paused) {
        v.interval = setInterval(function () {
            O(g.fwd, !1)
        }, r.animspeed);
        v.paused = !1
    }
})
```